# Казахский/казацкий

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Казахский/казацкий.

Comment: Это не совсем для нашего сайта вопрос. Вам нужно на географический форум, там уже привыкли объяснять, как правильно: Иран или Ирак.

Comment: Это очень правильный вопрос! Для нашего сайта по ОРФОГРАФИИ.  Почему мы используем разные суффиксы К/СК.  Так что не надо отсылать на географический форум, там географией занимаются, а не орфографией.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Орфографический словарь:**

(1) казацкий (от казак)

(2) казахский (к казахи и Казахстан)

**СУФФИКС СК/К ДЛЯ ГЕОГРАФИЧЕСКИХ НАЗВАНИЙ**

В большинстве случаев в географических и других названиях действуют **те же правила употребления суффиксов СК и К**, а именно:

суффикс относительных прилагательных ***СК*** является **основным вариантом:** швед – шведский, киргиз – киргизский, **казах – казахский,** Ташкент – ташкентский, тунгус – тунгусский, черкес – черкесский.

Суффикс относительных прилагательных ***К*** пишется после ***Ц***, а также при чередовании ***К на Ц*:**

немец – немецкий – основа на Ц, суффикс К;

калмык – калмыцкий, **казак – казацкий.**